# Can't find path to put images in a list?

Tags: python, path

I'm having some trouble getting my path to work when opening a folder. I put the folder of images into the same folder as the .py file that I'm coding in. Then I try to open it with this code:

```py
images = []
for file in glob('./images/*.PNG'):
    print(file)
    im = Image.open(file)
    images.append(im)
```

This, however, isn't working. I typed out the "print(file)" so I could see if it was even opening the file and it doesn't seem to even be doing that. I think it's a pathing issue but I have no idea because (as far as I'm concerned) that's the correct path. To reiterate, this "images" directory is in the same directory as the .py file I'm writing in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Maybe the directory name is misspelled? glob returns a list does `Image.open` accept a list of strings?

Comment: I can confirm that the directory name is spelled correctly. Think I'm going to take a different, less pretty approach to this given that this method isn't working even though it seems as if it should (like you said, couldn't replicate). Racking my brain over this won't further the project.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually what I did when I need to access a file inside *path*:

```
import os

pathCurrent = os.getcwd() + '\\'
imageFile = pathCurrent + '*.PNG'
```

And then you can use it as:

```
images = []
for file in glob(imageFile):
    print(file)
    im = Image.open(file)
    images.append(im)
```

Let me know if this help.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help in any way. I think I'm going to abandon this approach given that it *should* by all accounts work. I've figured a working, albeit less pretty, method to do this. Although, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```py
images = []

def is_img(p: Path) -> bool:
    return p.suffix.upper() in ('.PNG', '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.ICO', '.BMP')

for file in glob('./images/*'):
    if not is_img(file):
        print(file.suffix)
        continue
    print(file)
    im = Image.open(file)
    images.append(im)
```